# Free 2d array of char with realloc

Tags: c, arrays, free, realloc

In the following code, when I'm trying to free the individual elements of the 2D array of character (i.e. 2dArray[l]), I got an error (_crtisvalidheappointer(puserdata) dbgheap.c):
Any idea about the reason of the error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){    
    char ** TwodArray= NULL;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;

    do{
        k++;
        for (int i= 0; i<10; i++){
            j++;
            TwodArray=(char**)realloc(TwodArray, (j+1)*10*sizeof(char*));
            TwodArray[j-1]=(char*)malloc(10 *sizeof(char));
            TwodArray[j-1] = "abcdefgh";
            ....
        }        
    }while(k<3)
    // free the memory
    for (int l = 0; l < j; l++){
        if (TwodArray[l] != NULL)
            free(TwodArray[l]); // here I get the error!
    }
    free(TwodArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us some *real* code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The real code is complex and very long, I have tried to make it simple here! There is not any compiling error but the runtime error as I mentioned in the post: '_crtisvalidheappointer(puserdata) dbgheap.c

Comment: Well @Homer the problem is this code isn't even c. `2dArray` is an invalid parameter name. Anyhow after fixing missing includes, ; for your do while loop and the parameter name to get something working -- this snippet works.

Comment: There is **no** 2D array in your code, noting which can represent one nor point to one. A pointer is not an array. Freeing a 2D array is as simple as `free(my2Darray);`.

Comment: @IshayPeled
Now it breaks! I added the `TwodArray[j-1] = "abcdefgh";` line to the code

Comment: @Olaf When I simply `free(my2Darray)`, there is memory leak with each elements as I checked by vld!

Comment: @Homer: Read my comment **completely and carefully** again! What again did I write in the first sentence?

Comment: The try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). that you can show us. Without some actual real code it's really hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to free a static string.

If you write something like

```
char* a = "hello";
```

a isn't pointing to a dynamically memory zone. It is static, so you can't free it.

Answer (score 0):

```
TwodArray[j-1] = "abcdefgh";
```

followed by

```
free(TwodArray[l]);   // with l = j -1 from above
```

will fail because the value of `TwodArray[j-1]` doesn't point to something allocated by `malloc`

Did you wanted to do:

```
strcpy(TwodArray[j-1], "abcdefgh");
```

The explanation is that `TwodArray[j-1] = "abcdefgh";` changes the value of the pointer `TwodArray[j-1]` while `strcpy(TwodArray[j-1], "abcdefgh");` copies the string `"abcdefgh"` to the location pointed to by `TwodArray[j-1]` (and leaves the value of `TwodArray[j-1]` unchanged).

**Example of failing code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main (void)
{
  char* p = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
  printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
  p = "aaaa";                  // Bad....
  printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
  free(p);
  return 1;
}
```

> Possible output
>
> 0x1b76010
>
> 0x400688
>
> *** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400688 ***
>
> Aborted

**Example of working code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
  char* p = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
  printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
  strcpy(p, "aaaa");
  printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
  printf("%s\n", p);
  free(p);
  return 1;
}
```

> Possible output
>
> 0x1d2c010
>
> 0x1d2c010
>
> aaaa

Answer (score -1):

In short, don't free static strings:

```
char *a = "aaaa";
free(a)
```

Will cause the same error.

This will work:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char ** TwodArray= NULL;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;

    do{
        k++;
        for (int i= 0; i<10; i++){
            j++;
            TwodArray=(char**)realloc(TwodArray, (j+1)*10*sizeof(char*));
            TwodArray[j-1] = strndup("abcdefgh",8);
        }
    }while(k<3);
    // free the memory
    for (int l = 0; l < j; l++){
        if (TwodArray[l] != NULL)
            free(TwodArray[l]); // here I get the error!
    }
    free(TwodArray);
    return 0;
}
```